# Scroll bar, if Items exceed inside itemControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have **`ItemControl`**

It displays **one panel** for each record inside `ObservableCollection`.

My Problem is….

When size of ObservableCollection increase window can’t accommodate more panels so it displays **only first six panels.**

So criteria, One panel for each record inside ObservableCollection,couldn't be accomplish.

So, I need  to have scroll bar so I can access each panel.
How does it can be implement?

See one screen shot below and [Code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JA5EWd66K7lI3G2rlno0mjO1dvz1VR131hfIbH0i12s/edit?hl=en_US&authkey=CNWwr7EF#) of It Here

[image]

Thanks......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to host your panel within a `ScrollViewer`. This allows it to grow beyond the space available to it, whilst the `ScrollViewer` adds a Scrollbar.

You can do this by modiyfing the `ItemsControl` template:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
     <ScrollViewer>
       <ItemsPresenter/>
     </ScrollViewer>
   </ControlTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: is there any way to put restriction on WrapPanel, say it can display only 10 items in One row....and then go for new line.....Thanks........

Answer (score 0):

Put any controls you want to have scrollbars into the [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx). Example taken from MSDN:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,20">Scrolling is enabled when it is necessary. 
      Resize the window, making it larger and smaller.</TextBlock>
      <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="500" Height="500"></Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
```